# Sum of Sum in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

Can you guys please help me on this? I have written a query to get `DocumentNo`, `Whscode` and `NetAmmount` of each document like shown below:

```
SELECT t1.whscode,
CASE WHEN t0.[DiscPrcnt]>0 then ((sum(t1.LineTotal) -isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))-    ((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0)) * t0.[DiscPrcnt]/100)) +t0.VatSum 
ELSE ((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))) END
as 'NetAmount',t0.docnum
from [dbo].[OINV]  T0 (NOLOCK)  INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 (NOLOCK)  ON T0. [DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
where t0.docdate between '02-09-17' and '02-10-17' and
t1.WhsCode='kidst'and t0.CANCELED!='Y' and t1.targettype!=13
group by T0.[CardName],t0.[taxdate],t0.[docduedate], T0.[DocStatus], t0.[doctotal]-t0.[vatsum],
t1.whscode,t0.DocNum,t0.usersign,t0.DiscPrcnt,t0.dpmamnt,t0.vatsum
having (sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))>0
```

**Output:**

```
  |whscode| NetAmount   | docnum| 
  |KIDST  | 2147.419293 |3411592|
  |KIDST  |  19.000011  |3411670|
  |KIDST  |  23.380000  |3411314|
  |KIDST  |  50.000000  |3412061|
  |KIDST  |  268.720000 |3412000|
  |KIDST  |  69.930000  |3412289|
```

Now I would like to get the output as `Whscode` and sum of `NetAmount` like:

```
  |Whscode| NetAmount | 
   KIDST----2578.449
```

If I do `sum`(case to end) throwing an error of **Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.** 
Please can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Remove the field ' docnum' from your query (from both select and group by )

Comment: If I remove also its showing same error.
 SELECT t1.whscode,
sum(CASE WHEN t0.[DiscPrcnt]>0 then ((sum(t1.LineTotal) -isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))-((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0)) * t0.[DiscPrcnt]/100)) +t0.VatSum 
ELSE ((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))) END)
 as 'NetAmount'
from [dbo].[OINV]  T0 (NOLOCK)  INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 (NOLOCK)  ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
where t0.docdate between '02-09-17' and '02-10-17' and
t1.WhsCode='kidst'
 and t0.CANCELED!='Y' and t1.targettype!=13
 group by 
t1.whscode

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
;with cte as (
 SELECT t1.whscode,
 CASE WHEN t0.[DiscPrcnt]>0 then ((sum(t1.LineTotal) -isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))-    ((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0)) * t0.[DiscPrcnt]/100)) +t0.VatSum 
 ELSE ((sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))) END
 as 'NetAmount',t0.docnum
 from [dbo].[OINV]  T0 (NOLOCK)  INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 (NOLOCK)  ON  T0. [DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
where t0.docdate between '02-09-17' and '02-10-17' and
t1.WhsCode='kidst'and t0.CANCELED!='Y' and t1.targettype!=13
group by T0.[CardName],t0.[taxdate],t0.[docduedate], T0.[DocStatus], t0.[doctotal]-t0.[vatsum],
t1.whscode,t0.DocNum,t0.usersign,t0.DiscPrcnt,t0.dpmamnt,t0.vatsum
having (sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))>0 
)
select whscode,sum(Netamount) as NetAmount
 from cte
 group by whscode
```

Comment: same error.  Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: can you try inserting it in  `Temptable`? then get the sum of `NetAmount`

Comment: Yes i have tried same, still no luck. Same error showing

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `having (sum(t1.LineTotal)-isnull(t0.dpmamnt,0))>0 `

Comment: I removed having clause part also. still same error.

Comment: @Naveen.A Are you sure that your query runs before you try to get the total sum? It seems very strange to me that Jacky's answer doesn't work and netiher do temp tables.